# Input in a grid

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

Hi guys i have al this input boxes and i want to put them like in a 3x4  or 4x3 like on a  grid (i don't want them to stay one under the others), i've tried to use grid or other code but simply this don't work.
Do you know how to solve this ? this is the popup for a chrome extension so i don't have the maximum width maybe that's why.

```css
html {
  background-color: #d63031
}

input {
  border: white solid;
  background: #;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #574026;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width:600px">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p style="font-size:smaller"><em>Text</em></p>
  <p>Nome: <input placeholder="Name and Surname" id="nome"></p>
  <p>mail: <input placeholder="Email" id="mail"></p>
  <p>tel: <input placeholder="Telephone" id="tel"></p>
  <p>addr: <input placeholder="Address" id="indirizzo"></p>
  <p>City: <input placeholder="City" id="citta"></p>
  <p>PostCod: <input placeholder="PosteCode" id="pc"></p>

  <p>CardNumber: <input placeholder="Card Number" id="provola"></p>
  <p>CountryCode <input placeholder="IT,UK,...." id="paese"></p>
  <p>Card Type <input placeholder="american_express, master, visa, solo, paypal" id="tipo"></p>
  <p>ExpirationMonth: <input placeholder="01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12" id="mese"></p>
  <p>ExpirationYear: <input placeholder="2018,2019..." id="anno"></p>
  <p>Cvv: <input id="cvv"></p>



  <p><input style="background-color:#6c5ce7;border:none;" type="submit" id="send"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not clear what you're asking. Could you provide a screenshot or something of the desired result ?

Comment: @ths like this https://i.gyazo.com/0d7d8a16d1ece15f01dcf04cf22e12ac.png

Comment: use input types and if you specify an input **pattern** (for number fields like tel number), it'll make your life easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you're saying, but you can try [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
I kept your code the same but add div wrapper with a class of `.input-group` to your inputs.

I also recommend you use labels for your inputs and change your `<p>` to `<div>`

```
html {
  background-color: #d63031
}

body{
  width: 600px;
}

.input-group{
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box; 
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex; 
}

.input-group p{
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.input-group input{
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  display: block;
  border: white solid;
  background: #;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #574026;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
}

  <p>Text</p>
  <p style="font-size:smaller"><em>Text</em></p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <p>Nome: <input placeholder="Name and Surname" id="nome"></p>
    <p>mail: <input placeholder="Email" id="mail"></p>
    <p>tel: <input placeholder="Telephone" id="tel"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <p>addr: <input placeholder="Address" id="indirizzo"></p>
    <p>City: <input placeholder="City" id="citta"></p>
    <p>PostCod: <input placeholder="PosteCode" id="pc"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <p>CardNumber: <input placeholder="Card Number" id="provola"></p>
    <p>CountryCode <input placeholder="IT,UK,...." id="paese"></p>
    <p>Card Type <input placeholder="american_express, master, visa, solo, paypal" id="tipo"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <p>ExpirationMonth: <input placeholder="01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12" id="mese"></p>
    <p>ExpirationYear: <input placeholder="2018,2019..." id="anno"></p>
    <p>Cvv: <input id="cvv"></p>
  </div>



  <p><input style="background-color:#6c5ce7;border:none;" type="submit" id="send"></p>
```

Comment: thk you so much

Comment: it's not just labels, but input TYPES that need using also.

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to have maximum width for grids to work. Here is a working solution, although it wasn't very clear what you want to achieve, so let me know if I missed something.

You need to have a container for your grid system, and you need to put the input boxes that you want to group into a div, like the following:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div id="grid-1">
        <p>Nome: <input placeholder="Name and Surname" id="nome"></p>
        <p>mail: <input placeholder="Email" id="mail"></p>
        <p>tel: <input placeholder="Telephone" id="tel"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="grid-2">
        <p>addr: <input placeholder="Address" id="indirizzo"></p>
        <p>City: <input placeholder="City" id="citta"></p>
        <p>PostCod: <input placeholder="PosteCode" id="pc"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="grid-3">
        <p>CardNumber: <input placeholder="Card Number" id="provola"></p>
        <p>CountryCode <input placeholder="IT,UK,...." id="paese"></p>
        <p>Card Type <input placeholder="american_express, master, visa, solo, paypal" id="tipo"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="grid-4">
        <p>ExpirationMonth: <input placeholder="01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12" id="mese"></p>
        <p>ExpirationYear: <input placeholder="2018,2019..." id="anno"></p>
        <p>Cvv: <input id="cvv"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the CSS side, you need to specify a display grid for the container, and tell the divs containing the input boxes in which column they should go.

```
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

#grid-1 {
    grid-column: 1/2;
}

#grid-2 {
    grid-column: 2/3;
}

#grid-3 {
    grid-column: 3/4;
}

#grid-4 {
    grid-column: 4/5;
}
```

Like this, all your input boxes will be nicely grouped up and lined up next to each other. Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above CSS, the first column will have a fixed width of 200px whilst the second will take 1fr (“one fraction”) of the remaining available space.

```css
html {
  background-color: #d63031
}
body{display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;}

input {
  border: white solid;
  background: #;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #574026;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7) 0 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width:600px">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p style="font-size:smaller"><em>Text</em></p>
  <p>Nome: <input placeholder="Name and Surname" id="nome"></p>
  <p>mail: <input placeholder="Email" id="mail"></p>
  <p>tel: <input placeholder="Telephone" id="tel"></p>
  <p>addr: <input placeholder="Address" id="indirizzo"></p>
  <p>City: <input placeholder="City" id="citta"></p>
  <p>PostCod: <input placeholder="PosteCode" id="pc"></p>

  <p>CardNumber: <input placeholder="Card Number" id="provola"></p>
  <p>CountryCode <input placeholder="IT,UK,...." id="paese"></p>
  <p>Card Type <input placeholder="american_express, master, visa, solo, paypal" id="tipo"></p>
  <p>ExpirationMonth: <input placeholder="01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12" id="mese"></p>
  <p>ExpirationYear: <input placeholder="2018,2019..." id="anno"></p>
  <p>Cvv: <input id="cvv"></p>



  <p><input style="background-color:#6c5ce7;border:none;" type="submit" id="send"></p>
</body>

</html>
```